# Will Allah forgive my brother for abandoning parents?

Tags: allah, tawba

My brother abandoned my mom after getting married. I looked after my mom. He only realized his mistake after my mom's death. I know he is guilty and repents. But my question is will Allah forgive my brother? I can't see him in pain.  Will Allah accept his forgiveness?  Just tell me the way my brother can repent and doesn’t face Allah's punishment?

Answer (score 0):

Allah can and is willing to forgive all who believe in Him and ask for forgiveness and repent. Not all sins can be made undone but all sins can be forgiven to a believer.

Comment: He is repenting and regretting the fact that he was not with her in her last moment. He abandoned and now he is doing everything to gain Almighty's forgiveness. He realized his mistakes. Will Allah forgive him?

Comment: Inshallah Allah will forgive him, just say to him not to loose hope and keep asking for forgiveness to Allah, Allah is the most forgiving most merciful.